# shift() and list() inside DT don't work with rowMeans

Tags: r, data.table

Trying to calculate mean over 4 last values in DT. Thought the following would work:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1:10)
dt[, means := rowMeans(shift(a, 0:3), na.rm = TRUE)]
```

but it returns `'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`

so I tested with

```
lags <- paste0("a.lag", c(1,2,3))
dt[, (lags) := shift(a, 1:3)]
dt[, means := rowMeans(c("a", lags), na.rm = TRUE)]
```

same error. Surprisingly, the following works:

```
dt[, means := rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = c("a", lags)]
```

Why is .SD returning a 2-dimensional array here but not the other? Is it a bug or am I missing something? Using DT 1.11.9.

Comment: Try shift(dt$a) -- it's a list. You can setDT() on it to make a (2D) data.table.

Comment: Thanks! Problem is I'm doing this over 100k+ groups in a very large DT. Don't understand why .SD returns something different here. But at least it works :)

Comment: Cool, glad it works. Fwiw, .SD appears in only one line of code, so I don't know what is meant by "not the other" here.

Comment: Sorry .SD returns the array that rowMeans can work with, but the other = shift(.) directly or returning a subset DT doesn't.

Comment: Is it a bug? Shouldn't shift() also return a data table?